# Tomcat запускается на VPS, но из браузера не удаётся что-то увидеть

Tags: java, linux, сервер, debian, tomcat

**Дано:**

Сервер на Debian с доступом по ssh.

**Задача:**

Вывести "HelloWorld" в браузере по адресу сервера.

**Что пробовал:**

Пробовал гуглить. Насколько понял надо Tomcat установить и запустить. Вроде установил и запустил ([по этой инструкции](https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-debian/)) но по адресу сервера всё также пусто. Смотрел что на порте 8080. Всё что там было потёр из системы.

**Подозрения**:

Кажется что-то не так с явой. Ни одна из инструкций не помогла установить 8 версию. Последний раз вот это пробовал: [тык](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-install-oracle-jdk-8-on-debian/)

**Вопрос:**

После нескольких статей, ни одна из которых не приводит к результату хочется узнать что и как надо сделать чтобы что-то получилось. Хотя бы куда смотреть и что гуглить.

---

UPD:

- Переустановил ОС, теперь Debian 8
- Поставил пакетом 8 Java
- Поставил пакетом 8 Tomcat
- При попытке запуска ругается на неустановленную JAVA_HOME

Попробовал вот так установить оную:

```
JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:bin/javac::")
```

Теперь `echo $JAVA_HOME` выдаёт

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/
```

Но Tomcat всё также ругается на неустановленный JAVA_HOME

Comment: а что в логах у Tomcat?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, `/opt/tomcat8/bin/catalina.sh: 1: eval: /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_66/bin/java: not found` и да, там нет такой папки... Сейчас попробую как-то туда такую запихнуть...

Comment: При этом там есть `/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java`

Comment: у вас явно что-то не так встало. попробуйте поставить все из пакетов, а не руками.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, я вот сейчас попробовал через winSCP скопировать папку с явой 66 и да, ничего не поменялось. Как я понял в Debian нельзя не руками 8 версию явы поставить( А вот руками никак и не выходит... Сейчас ещё раз попробую. Наверное я не туда куда-то ставлю.

Comment: яву нельзя, а джаву можно.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, попробовал [по этой инструкции](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html) поставить, но пишет `Unable to locate package`

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, о, с 3 раза получилось джаву 8 поставить!

Comment: рекомендую ставить OpenJDK - меньше проблем с установкой.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, да мне бы хоть какую-нибудь... Теперь вот попытался [вот так](https://wolfpaulus.com/java/tomcat-jessie/) поставить Tomcat опять, но в итоге в `/usr/share/tomcat` пусто, т.е. папку такую не находит, хотя и ошибок никаких не выдавал в процессе(

Comment: поставьте все из пакетов. не руками.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, я попробовал сейчас чере гугл узнать как это сделать и ничего не нашёл. Вы имеете в виду apt-get? Он мне на `apt-get install tomcat8` выдаёт `The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tomcat8 : Depends: tomcat8-common (>= 8.5.11-1~bpo8+2) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: libtcnative-1 (>= 1.2.6~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, таки удалось запустить. И у меня есть подозрение что с open-jdk действительно было бы проще... Спасибо за комментарии - они помогли на нужный путь выйти)

Comment: скорее всего `export JAVA_HOME=...` решил бы проблему, насколько понимаю, при такой установке переменные окружения не унаследовались бы дочерним процессом

Comment: @etki, вроде я пытался так делать... Для меня более всего удивительно, что эта переменная автоматически не устанавливается при установке явы. Я конечно слышал, что линукс система с особенностями, но не ожидал, что придётся реально править код первой же программы, которая мне понадобится)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге удалось так сделать:

1. Установил Java 8 через apt-get
2. Установил Tomcat 8 через apt-get
3. При установке Tomcat создался файл `tomcat8` в папке `/etc/init.d`
4. В нём кто-то накосячил (в коде с попыткой вычисления пути до Java) и пришлось руками проставить нужный путь. В моём случае:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/
```

сразу перед

```
export JAVA_HOME
```

Насколько я понял, код из автоматически созданного скрипта не учитывал вариант пути с `java` и `jre`, т. е. там были варианты типа `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-${java_version}-oracle`, `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-${java_version}-oracle` и `/usr/lib/jvm/java-${java_version}-openjdk`, но нигде у них не было `jre` на конце.

После добавления указанной выше строки в файл, в браузере по адресу `http://IP:8080` появилась страница и я могу редактировать её html.

<s>Я написал туда много мата.</s>